# A variation of the randomized min-cut algorithm

Tags: probability, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, computer-science

This is an exercise (1.25 (c)) from the book "[Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis" by Mitchenmacher and Upfal](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/spa/courses/uj16/mu-book.pdf)" (page 19).

The exercise asks to modify the [randomized min-cut algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm) (also presented in the book starting from page 12) so that we first contract the graph down to $k$ vertices using the algorithm and then run the randomized algorithm on the reduced graph $l$ times. The problem is to find optimal (or near optimal) values for $k$ and $l$ that maximize the probability of finding a min-cut while using the same number of edge contractions as when running the original algorithm twice. Here is my solution thus far:

The probability of finding a min-cut is bound by the probability of not contracting an edge from the min-cut in the first $n-k$ iterations and not contracting an edge from the min-cut in a least one of the $l$ branches for the remaining $k-2$ nodes. The latter probability can be computed as a complement of contracting at least one edge in the min-cut in each of the $l$ branches. Let $F_i$ be the event that no edge from the min-cut is contracted in the first $i$ iterations. We can compute a lower bound for the probability $\Pr(F_{n-k})$ similarly as in the original version of the randomized min-cut algorithm:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \Pr(F_{n-k}) \geq \prod_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac{n-i-1}{n-i+1} = \frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Furthermore, the probability of not contracting an edge from the min-cut in the remaining $k-2$ iterations is $\Pr(F_{k-2})$, which we can bound similarly:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \Pr(F_{k-2}) \geq \prod_{i=1}^{k-2}\frac{k-i-1}{k-i+1} = \frac{2}{k(k-1)}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Now, the probability of our modified algorithm returning the min-cut is
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:68}
\begin{split}
    \Pr(F_{n-k}) \cdot (1 - (1 - \Pr(F_{k-2}))^l) \geq \frac{k(k-1)(1 - (1 - \frac{2}{k(k-1)})^l)}{n(n-1)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus, the problem reduces to the problem of maximizing $k(k-1)(1 - (1 - \frac{2}{k(k-1)})^l)$ with a constraint $n - k + l(k-2) \leq 2n-4
$ (the constraint comes from the number of edge contractions). This is what I'm struggling with. The expression that should be maximized is ugly, and I haven't been able to come up with any strategy for maximizing it. Can someone point me if there is some flaw in my reasoning above or help me with the maximization task?

Note that the modified algorithm here is not the recursive version of randomized the min-cut algorithm, though that would be a more optimal solution for this min-cut problem.